# My R app produces extra additional output on the body

Tags: r, shiny

This is my R code :

```
library("RJSDMX")
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Navlist panel example"),

  navlistPanel(
    "Header",
    result <- array(getFlows("TurkStat")),

    boyut1 <- getDimensions("TurkStat","RD_A"),
    boyut2 <- getDimensions("TurkStat","STSALL"),
    boyut3 <- getDimensions("TurkStat","NA_MAIN"),

     selected = result[1],
#    boy_tab1 <- as.data.frame.table(boyut1),
#    boy_tab2 <- as.data.frame.table(boyut2),
#    boy_tab3 <- as.data.frame.table(boyut3),

    tabPanel(result[1], as.data.frame.list(boyut1)),
    tabPanel(result[2], as.data.frame.list(boyut2)),
    tabPanel(result[3], as.data.frame.list(boyut3))
    )
  )

server = function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When the page loads the result output displays completely :

RD data structure definition STS ALL NA Main Aggregates tab-9265-2 SDMX/CL_FREQ/2.0 ESTAT/CL_GEO_RD/1.2 ESTAT/CL_SECTFUND/1.2 ESTAT/CL_SECTFUND/1.2 ESTAT/CL_SEX/2.0 ESTAT/CL_RD_OCCUP/1.1 ESTAT/CL_FORD/1.0 ESTAT/CL_AGE/2.0 ESTAT/CL_GEO_RD/1.2 ESTAT/CL_ISCED11_RD/1.0 ESTAT/CL_SENIORITY/1.0 ESTAT/CL_TYPECOST/1.1 ESTAT/CL_TYPERD/1.1 ESTAT/CL_AFFILIATION/1.0 ESTAT/CL_INDUSTRY/1.1 ESTAT/CL_INDUSTRY/1.1 ESTAT/CL_EMPLOYEES/1.1 ESTAT/CL_NABS07/1.1 ESTAT/CL_RD_UNIT/1.1 tab-9265-3 SDMX/CL_FREQ/2.0 IMF/CL_AREA/1.5 ESTAT/CL_ADJUSTMENT/1.4 ESTAT/CL_STS_INDICATOR/1.1 ESTAT/CL_ACTIVITY_STS/1.0 ESTAT/CL_BASE_YEAR/1.1 tab-9265-4 SDMX/CL_FREQ/2.0 ESTAT/CL_ADJUSTMENT/1.4 IMF/CL_AREA/1.7 IMF/CL_AREA/1.7 ESTAT/CL_SECTOR/1.5 ESTAT/CL_SECTOR/1.5 IMF/CL_ACCOUNT_ENTRY/1.2 ESTAT/CL_NA_STO/1.8 ESTAT/CL_INSTR_ASSET/1.6 ESTAT/CL_ACTIVITY/1.5 ESTAT/CL_COICOP/1.1 IMF/CL_UNIT/1.8 ESTAT/CL_NA_PRICES/1.1 ESTAT/CL_TRANSFORMATION/1.2 tab-9265-5
SDMX/CL_FREQ/2.0 ESTAT/CL_GEO_RD/1.2 ESTAT/CL_SECTFUND/1.2 ESTAT/CL_SECTFUND/1.2 ESTAT/CL_SEX/2.0 ESTAT/CL_RD_OCCUP/1.1 ESTAT/CL_FORD/1.0 ESTAT/CL_AGE/2.0 ESTAT/CL_GEO_RD/1.2 ESTAT/CL_ISCED11_RD/1.0 ESTAT/CL_SENIORITY/1.0 ESTAT/CL_TYPECOST/1.1 ESTAT/CL_TYPERD/1.1 ESTAT/CL_AFFILIATION/1.0 ESTAT/CL_INDUSTRY/1.1 ESTAT/CL_INDUSTRY/1.1 ESTAT/CL_EMPLOYEES/1.1 ESTAT/CL_NABS07/1.1 ESTAT/CL_RD_UNIT/1.1

I just want to display the result when I make a selection on the sidebar. But it shows my selection after displaying all the result.

Can you please help me how I can clear the body of the page to make it possible it behaves as according to my selections?

Thank you very much.

best regards.

Comment: The logic of what you want to do in R doesn't belong in the `ui` function. There should only be _declarative_ code, describing the elements of your interface. The code that uses those inputs and generates those outputs belongs to `server`. You'd need to (re)read an introductory tutorial to Shiny. I suggest you start here: http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/#first-app or there: http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/. The learning resources on this website are amazing!

Comment: Thank you very much for the links. I will read them.